# Getting error on iOS machine when running react native project through Xcode. Error code is -999

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I just finished development on Windows machine for Android device in React Native and when tried to run same code on Mac with Xcode having bundle load issue with could not connect to development server error.

I tried following solution but did not get any success

1. kill all node (running on 8081 port)
2. Change in localhost path

For error details please see below image.

[image: react native error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you are not developing app on iOS platform, source code is written & tested on windows so probably there is setup (or config) issue on mac machine.
>
> So to solve this issue install react native on mac machine with same react native version and try again by killing all processes those are running on 8081 port.